# How can I combine records on the basis of some conditions

Tags: oracle, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have following table,

```
id   id_concept  start_date  end_date
----------------------------------------------
100    282        20/06/2016  24/06/2016 
100    282        15/07/2016  18/07/2016
300    282        01/09/2016  02/09/2016
```

I need to combine the records which has same id,id_concept and the time between END_DATE of one record and START_DATE of the next is 30 days or less (<=30)

Also for the combined records, I need to take the start_date as the very first start_date of the record and end _date as the end_date of the last record

The o/p should be like,

```
     id    id_concept start_date  end_date      count
    ---------------------------------------------------
    100    282        20/06/2016  18/07/2016      2
    300    282        01/09/2016  02/09/2016      1
```

Comment: Please add only tags that are relevant for the DBMS you are using. Do you really use Oracle **and** Postgres **and** Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/15881/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, id_concept, start_date, end_date ) AS
SELECT 100, 282, DATE '2016-06-20', DATE '2016-06-24' UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 282, DATE '2016-07-15', DATE '2016-07-18' UNION ALL
SELECT 300, 282, DATE '2016-09-01', DATE '2016-09-02';
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id,
       id_concept,
       MIN( start_date ) AS start_date,
       MAX( end_date ) AS end_date,
       COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         id_concept,
         start_date,
         end_date,
         SUM( diff ) OVER (
           PARTITION BY id, id_concept
           ORDER BY start_date, end_date
         ) AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           CASE
           WHEN LAG( end_date ) OVER (
                  PARTITION BY id, id_concept
                  ORDER BY start_date, end_date
                ) >= start_date - INTERVAL '30' DAY
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END AS diff
    FROM   table_name t
  ) t
) t
GROUP BY id, id_concept, grp
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/15881/1/0)**:

```
|  id | id_concept |                  start_date |                    end_date | count |
|-----|------------|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|-------|
| 300 |        282 | September, 01 2016 00:00:00 | September, 02 2016 00:00:00 |     1 |
| 100 |        282 |      June, 20 2016 00:00:00 |      July, 18 2016 00:00:00 |     2 |
```

Comment: @MTO....Getting an error "Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause" . Could you please check it

Comment: @Chinnu The SQL Fiddle above works and does not generate that error. Can you post a new question with an example of what you are doing that generates the error as I cannot replicate it.